# Ionic2 - Popover (ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I am getting the following error when I tried to implement **Popover**:

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Here is my code:

```
import {Popover, Page, NavController, MenuController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';

 @Component({
template: 'This is a popover'
 })

 class MyPopover{}

 export class HomePage {

 constructor(nav, http, navParams) {}

 //PopOver
  showPopover(ev){
     let popover = Popover.create(MyPopover);
     this.nav.present(popover, {
       ev: ev
 })
 }}
```

Anyone knows why I am getting this?
I believe that there is an issue while importing **Popover** as I am doing the below just after importing **Popover**:

`console.log("Popover object : ",{Popover})`

I am getting `undefined` so mostly the issue is there.

Comment: What Ionic 2 version are you currently on? Popover has only been recently added. Try updating to the latest beta.

Comment: I am using Ionic2  Beta  7

Comment: Upgrade to Beta 10 (latest as of today). Here are the release notes: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 3):

I think you were missing the `@Component` in your `HomePage`

```
@Component({
  template: `This is a popover`
})

export class MyPopover{}


// This @Component declaration was missing in your code
@Component({
  templateUrl:"build/pages/home/home.html"
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(private nav: NavController) { }       

  //PopOver
  public showPopover(ev){
     let popover = Popover.create(MyPopover);
     this.nav.present(popover, {
       ev: ev
     });    
  }
}
```

With that (and using beta.9 at least) the `popover` is working properly. You can play around with this code in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/siM0dIe69q9HeTnCOzyr?p=preview).